# How to read message TCP server in Visual Basic. NET?

Tags: vb.net, sockets

I have a `TCP server` made ​​in `java` and I want to connect to `Visual Basic`. I have the following code

```
Try
    clientSocket.Connect("192.168.1.64", 4444)
    Label1.Text = "Cliente Conectado"
Catch ex As Exception
    Label1.Text = ex.ToString
End Try  

Dim TCPNetworkStream As NetworkStream = clientSocket.GetStream
Dim TCPStreamWriter As New StreamWriter(TCPNetworkStream)

TCPStreamWriter.Write(TextBox2.Text)
TCPStreamWriter.Close()
'TCPNetworkStream.Close()
'clientSocket.Close()
```

how can i get the text from the server?

Answer (score 0):

You have to read from the network stream using [`NetworkStream.Read`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.net.sockets.networkstream%28v=vs.110%29.aspx).